# Delete row using location of shape

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a row based on the location of a shape. In the screen shot there is a blue shape in B7, I would like to click on that shape, delete the row completely and shift the data below it up 1 row.

Once I have that I can copy the shape and accompanying macro on each row so the user can delete any name they want.

I did some searching and started off with this code.

```
Sub Delete_Borrower()
'Macros ro delete individual borrowers fron dbase
Dim mysht As Worksheet
Dim myDropDown As Shape
Dim MLO As Range
Set mysht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Borrower Database")
CallingShapeName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
Set MLO = Range(mysht.Shapes(CallingShapeName).TopLeftCell.Address)
MsgBox "OK" & MLO

'Code to delete row and shift rows below up one row

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So what is your specific question? The code is not working or what? As for the direction, I think you're on the right track.

Comment: I don’t know what code to write to actually make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub NoSymbol1_Click()

    Dim r As Range, shp As Shape
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell    'find the range of the button clicked.
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell = r.Address Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
    r.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```